# Overriding save queryset in django 1.6's Atomic Save?

Tags: python, django

Hello I have an app where I do atomic saves that was introduced in [Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) I would like to override the save method that saves them all at once, and peek into the queryset of the save.

Is that possible?